# Encrypt jquery/ajax call when posting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a jquery Ajax method which listen for the onlick of a button, when its clicked it makes a call to the controller and passes in some parameters which then goes on to call the database.

When I click the button I see the following in the developer tool bar console.

```
http://localhost:37495/user/SetProfilePicture?pictureId=2&_=1434199801182
```

Is there a way I can encrypt that? so its un-readable, someone on another forum mentioned about writing a special route for this particular situation but I can't seem to find anything on the web.

Update

This is what my code looks like I have been looking at the following example: 
[Encode/Decode URL Javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-decode-url-string/)

```
  $('.profilebutton').on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        var url = '/user/SetProfilePicture?pictureId=' +  $(this).attr("data-id") + '';

        $.ajax({
            url: encodeURIComponent(url),
            //data: { "pictureId": $this.attr("data-id") },
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $("div.thumbnail").removeClass("Photoactive");
                    $this.closest("div.thumbnail").addClass("Photoactive");
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Sorry, can not set profile picture at this time");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

But I get this error:

"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:37495/user/%2Fuser%2FSetProfilePicture%3FpictureId%3D3?_=1434452450966"

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the contents, but not the URL.  Re-write your ajax call to have all of your url parameters as part of the body.  The body can be encrypted.

Comment: I have added my markup I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.